# dock div to another DOM element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a an image in my body like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="one" src="img1.png" />
</div>
```

and when I'm hovering it appends a div:

```
function bindHover() {
    $("#one").hover(
            function() {
                $('#wrapper').append('<div id="hoverdiv"></div>');
            }
    )
}
```

what I would like to do is that the appended div's `#hoverdiv` position is directly below the img `#one`. As in this picture! [click me for example image](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/cdhlrqxq/Unbenannt2.jpg)

One important note is, that the position of `#one` isn't always the same, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Can you show demo of your problem on jsfiddle or jsbin?
I tried to create jsfiddle based on above code but dont see any problem http://jsfiddle.net/ZhbdW/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhbdW/2/ with better hower effect..

Comment: `after` to image id will always append next to it instead `append` to the parent id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function bindHover() {
  $("#one").hover(
   function() {

         var Position = $("#one").position();

         $('#wrapper').append('<div id="hoverdiv"></div>');

         $('#hoverdiv').css({'position': 'absolute',
                            'left': Position.left, 
                            'top': Position.top + $("#one").height()});

      }
   )}
```

Comment: appended div's #hoverdiv position is directly below the img #one

Comment: the position of #one isnt always the same,

Comment: Yeah, and that's what this code does: it gets the position of the image and positions the hoverdiv accordingly.

Comment: @TedMosby: depending on how your HTML is set up, you might need to change var Position = $("#one").position(); to var Position = $("#one").offset();

Comment: no because in your solution all the element coming after one should be absolute to work fine otherwise the first static element will overlap

Comment: Whatt??????? In fact, your solution isn't at all working: it adds the image in the DOM but it doesn't deal at all with positioning. What if you have #one{float:right;}

Comment: i am inserting html just after #one

Comment: Right, the node is below in the DOM but that doesn't mean it will be positioned below on the screen.

Comment: but that should be handled desperately and for sure not with absolute without considering rest of the element coming next. and atleast dom coming next will help in static positioning (the most general case)

Comment: thanks frenchie, works pretty well! Rohit as i said i needed to positioned it below the `#one`and its not always at left: 0, top:0. Otherwise yours would work!

Comment: @RohitAgrawal: "and for sure not with absolute without considering rest of the element coming next" not sure where you got this but it's not true; you can set any element's position to absolute if you need to.

Comment: @frenchie one question again, and i dont want to open an extra topic for that. when appending the div, isnt it possible to fade that in with `$('#wrapper').append('<div id="hoverdiv"></div>').fadeIn('slow');`because it doesnt work...

Comment: The .fadeIn() function as you wrote it is currently operating on $('#wrapper') since you have $('#wrapper').append().fadeIn(); what you want is to add .fadeIn() to $('#hoverdiv'), just after the .css() function that I wrote. Also, as a suggestion, using .hover() to trigger the function call isn't ideal because it's triggering the function many many times; I would replace that with .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() so that the function triggers only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#one").hover(
    function() {
        width=$(this).width();
      $('#wrapper').append('<div id="hovering" style="width:'+width+'px"></div>');
    },function() {
      $('#hovering').remove();
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhbdW/3/

Comment: Check the above answer I have made changes.